# Serialize() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, serialization

This works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, but not in IE8

```
var z = $($('form')[0].elements).not("#x, #y").serialize();
```

Field names and values of 'x' and 'y' are omitted from the serialize() output string.

ID and name attributes are the same for each element, `name="x"`, `id="x"` for one, `name="y"`, `id="y"` for the other.

But in IE the serialized form data always returns the name and value for element `id="x"` and `id="y"`, which I need to exclude as part of the form validation.

Is this a known bug in IE? I can find no specific solution to this problem online.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: `$('form :input:not(#x, #y)').serialize();`? Do you have several elements with the same name/id?

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfectly, thank you, you have just saved my dissertation ;)

Comment: Yey, I'm the hero of the day `\(^ ^)/` ... now, who helps me with my Master thesis? :D

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems the following works:

```
$('form :input:not(#x, #y)').serialize();
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted then (by clicking the tick outline next to it) :)